# Bicep reference : Can't find existing resources

Tags: automation, azure, templates, arm

Hi I'm devloping a bicep template with a bicep.main containing the modules
and seperate resources file for each resource

i have deployed a Nat Gateway and  a Network security group ,
now im trying to deploy a vnet/subnet which reference the nat gateway and the NSG

here is what the vnet.bicep file looks like :

```
param location string
param virtualNetworkName string
param vNetAddressSpace string
param subnetName string
param vNetSubnetPrefix string
param vNetNewOrExisting string
param natGatewayName string
param nsgName string

// reference the existing Nat Gateway and NSG
resource NAT_Gateway 'Microsoft.Network/natGateways@2021-05-01' existing =  {
  name: natGatewayName
}
resource nsg 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2021-05-01' existing= {
  name: nsgName
}

resource znssVnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-08-01' = if (vNetNewOrExisting == 'new') {
  name: virtualNetworkName
  location: location
  tags: {
    Owner: 'wguilherme'
    Purpose: 'ZscalerNSSDeployment'
  }
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        vNetAddressSpace
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: subnetName
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: vNetSubnetPrefix
          natGateway: {
            id: NAT_Gateway.id
          }
          networkSecurityGroup: {
            id: nsg.id
          }
          privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
          privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
        }
      }
    ]
    enableDdosProtection: false
    enableVmProtection: false
  }
}

resource znssSubnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-05-01' = {
  parent: znssVnet
  name: subnetName
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: vNetSubnetPrefix
    natGateway: {
      id: NAT_Gateway.id
    }
    privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
    privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
  }
}
```

i used **existing** to reference the NATG and NSG

with :

```
NAT_Gateway.id
and 
nsg.id
```

but the deployment fails with the error :

> Resource
> /subscriptions/-----/resourceGroups/RG-RSS00/providers/Microsoft.Network/natGateways/NATGW-NSS-SRVC-NIC
> referenced by resource
> /subscriptions/-----/resourceGroups/rg-rss00/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/Zscaler-NSS-VNET
> was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists,
> and that both resources are in the same region.

i checked the NATGW and the NSG are both deployed and in the same RG

here is what my main.bicep looks like :

```
targetScope='subscription'

param resourceGroupName string
param storageName string
param location string
param date string = utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')
param email string
param nsgNameFile string
param publicIPAddress1Name string
param publicIPAddress2Name string
param publicIPprefixName string
param SKU string
param StaticPublicIP string 
param natGatewayName string
param vNetNewOrExisting string = 'new'
param subnetName string
param virtualNetworkName string
param vNetAddressSpace string
param vNetSubnetPrefix string
param NSSMgtNIC string
param NSSSrvcNIC string

resource newRG 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-01-01' = {
  name: resourceGroupName
  location: location
}

module znssStorageAccountName 'storage.bicep' = {
  name: 'storageModule'
  scope: newRG
  params: {
    location: location
    storageName: storageName
  }
}
module nsg 'Networking.bicep'= {
name: 'NetworkingModel'
scope: newRG
params: {
 date: date
 location: location
 email: email
 nsgName: nsgNameFile
 publicIPAddress1Name: publicIPAddress1Name
 publicIPAddress2Name: publicIPAddress2Name
 publicIPprefixName: publicIPprefixName
 StaticPublicIP: StaticPublicIP
 SKU: SKU
 natGatewayName: natGatewayName
 vNetNewOrExisting: vNetNewOrExisting
 }
}

module vnet 'Vnet-Subnets.bicep' = {
  name: 'vnetModule'
  scope: newRG
  params: {
   location: location
   natGatewayName: natGatewayName
   nsgName: nsgNameFile
   subnetName: subnetName
   virtualNetworkName: virtualNetworkName
   vNetAddressSpace: vNetAddressSpace
   vNetNewOrExisting: vNetNewOrExisting
   vNetSubnetPrefix: vNetSubnetPrefix
  }
}
module nic 'NIC.bicep' = {
  name: 'nicModule'
  scope: newRG
  params: {
   location: location
   nsgName: nsgNameFile
   NSSMgtNIC: NSSMgtNIC
   NSSSrvcNIC: NSSSrvcNIC
   publicIPAddress1Name: publicIPAddress1Name
   publicIPAddress2Name: publicIPAddress2Name
   subnetName: subnetName
   virtualNetworkName: virtualNetworkName
   virtualNetworkResourceGroup: resourceGroupName
  }
}
```

the id in the error is the exact id as when i check on the portal , so it's not an id problem i think

im new to bicep so i hope someone can guide me to the right direction .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding the dependson propritie it worked !

```
dependsOn: [
    networking 
  ]
```

even though the Nat Gateway was created but the vnet creation was started before that

by adding the dependson it waits for the natgw to be created first

full example :

```
module vnet 'Vnet-Subnets.bicep' = {
  name: 'vnetModule'
  scope: newRG
  params: {
   location: location
   natGatewayName: natGatewayName
   nsgName: nsgNameFile
   subnetName: subnetName
   virtualNetworkName: virtualNetworkName
   vNetAddressSpace: vNetAddressSpace
   vNetNewOrExisting: vNetNewOrExisting
   vNetSubnetPrefix: vNetSubnetPrefix
  }
  dependsOn: [
    NATGW
  ]
```